# Sign of the totally anti-symmetric Levi-Civita tensor $\varepsilon^{\mu_1 \ldots}$ when raising indices

Tags: tensor-calculus, conventions

I am confused with the sign we get when we want to raise or lower all indices of the totally anti-symmetric tensor of any rank. Take the metric to be mostly plus ($-+\ldots+$). Then is it
$$\varepsilon^{ijk}=\varepsilon_{ijk}$$
or
$$\varepsilon^{ijk}=-\varepsilon_{ijk}?$$
so I am confused to as which one is true.
And if we consider higher rank does something change? For example
$$\varepsilon^{ijkl}=\varepsilon_{ijkl}$$
or
$$\varepsilon^{ijkl}=\varepsilon_{ijkl}?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not confusing by these things you must know exactly what are the Levi-Civita symbols $\varepsilon$ and what are the Levi-Civita tensor $\epsilon$. Then you also need to know that the Hodge dual has no any confusion when they had defined with Levi-Civita tensor. 
$$
\star H^{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\mu \nu}{}_{ \rho \sigma} H^{\rho \sigma}\Bigg( = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} H_{\rho \sigma}=-\frac{1} {2\sqrt{-g}}\varepsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} H_{\rho \sigma}\Bigg)
$$
and so
$$
\star H_{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{\mu \nu}{}^{ \rho \sigma} H_{\rho \sigma}\Bigg( = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} H^{\rho \sigma}=-\sqrt{-g}\varepsilon_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} H^{\rho \sigma}\Bigg)
$$

Answer (score 6):

In flat spacetime, the isomorphism between contra- and covariant components is furnished by the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$. The Minkowski metric in $n$ spacetime dimensions is just $\operatorname{diag}(-1,1,\dots,1)$. Thus for all dimensions, $$\operatorname{det}\eta=-1$$
For any $n\times n$ matrix $A_{\mu\nu}$, there is a well-known theorem
$$\epsilon_{\mu_1\cdots\mu_n}\operatorname{det}A=\sum_{i}\sum_{\nu_i}\epsilon_{\nu_1\cdots\nu_n}A_{\nu_1\mu_1}\cdots A_{\nu_n\mu_n}$$
where we have made no distinction between covariance and contravariance. But suppose $A=\eta$. Then all the multiplications by $\eta$ will raise the indices on $\epsilon$. And since $\operatorname{det}\eta=-1$ in any spacetime dimension, we get
$$\epsilon^{\cdots}=-\epsilon_{\cdots}$$
where the dots represent any number of indices.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I come to realize that my confusion arises from Wikipedia where they say that $\varepsilon_{\ldots}= + \varepsilon^{\ldots}$ because they are in Euclidean metric and not Minkowski.

Answer (score 3):

Sean Carroll's *Spacetime and Geometry* has a thorough discussion of this, and, even better, this discussion is in the [lecture notes](http://preposterousuniverse.com/grnotes/) that turned into the book (see Chapter 2: Manifolds).

In full generality (at least for any right-handed coordinate system), we start off with the *symbol* $\tilde{\epsilon}_{\mu_1\cdots\mu_n} \equiv [\mu_1\,\cdots\,\mu_n]$, which is $0$ or $\pm1$ depending on the sign of $\mu_1\,\cdots\,\mu_n$ as a permutation of $0\,\cdots\,(n-1)$. Then the *tensor* with lower indices obeys
$$ \epsilon_{\mu_1\cdots\mu_n} = \sqrt{\lvert g \rvert} \tilde{\epsilon}_{\mu_1\cdots\mu_n} = \sqrt{\lvert g \rvert}\ [\mu_1\,\cdots\,\mu_n], $$
where $g$ is the determinant of the metric.

Some people define a *symbol* with upper indices that is the same as that with lower indices, but on the other hand some people include an extra factor of $\operatorname{sgn}(g)$. In fact, this is ambiguous enough that Carroll states one version in the linked notes, and the other version in the final published book.

In any event, the *tensor* with upper indices is unambiguously
$$ \epsilon^{\mu_1\cdots\mu_n} = \frac{1}{g} \epsilon_{\mu_1\cdots\mu_n} = \frac{\operatorname{sgn}(g)}{\sqrt{\lvert g \rvert}} [\mu_1\,\cdots\,\mu_n]. $$

In the end, you should be using the full tensors in calculations, at least if everything else in the formula is a true tensor. In flat spacetime, the metric is $\operatorname{diag}(-1,+1,+1,+1)$, so $g = -1$ and we have
\begin{align}
\epsilon_{\mu_1\cdots\mu_n} & = \phantom{-}[\mu_1\,\cdots\,\mu_n], \\
\epsilon^{\mu_1\cdots\mu_n} & = -[\mu_1\,\cdots\,\mu_n].
\end{align}

Comment: So if the dual tensor is defined as $H^{\mu \nu} = -\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} H_{\rho \sigma} $ does the above mean that with indices down we have $H_{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} H^{\rho \sigma} $?

Comment: @Marion That's very confusing notation without Hodge stars, since $H^{\mu\nu}$ should by all rights be $g^{\mu\alpha} g^{\nu\beta} H_{\alpha\beta}$. In any case, we have $({}^*H)^{\mu\nu} = -(1/2)\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}H_{\rho\sigma}$. Then $(1/2)\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}({}^*H)^{\rho\sigma} = (1/2)g_{\mu\alpha}g_{\nu\beta}\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\rho\sigma}({}^*H)_{\rho\sigma} = -g_{\mu\alpha}g_{\nu\beta}({}^{**}H)^{\alpha\beta} = g_{\mu\alpha}g_{\nu\beta}H^{\alpha\beta} = H_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: But your first formula and my sign change from ${}^{**}H$ to $H$ depend on the dimension of the space, the number of indices on $H$, and the number of negative signs in the metric signature, so I don't guarantee this works if those things change.